# Can a program have a few IFs and only one Else structures?

Tags: jquery

When I was doing some JQuery and PHP, 
I noticed the If-else patterns were treated differently and varied from one language to another
.

Say I got a simple input text field in a HTML
and I was using some Ifs and Elses to check the
 value input into the text field.

```
Text: <input type="text" name="testing"/>
```

In JQuery, I got some codes as follows:

```
if($("#testing").val()==1){
//do something
}
if($("#testing").val()=="add"){
//do something
}
else{
//do something
}
if($("#testing").val()=="hello"){
//do something
}
```

How come JQuery and PHP treated the Else statement differently?
I mean in JQuery, the third If statement was 
still proceeded even if it had gone to the Else statement, 
but it stopped after the Else statement when I repeated the code in PHP script.

Comment: I highly doubt it. Please show your PHP code.

Comment: The patterns shouldn't be treated differently, they are pretty clear. Can you show the exact cases in jQuery and PHP, and show what data you used?

Comment: `if` statements are executed exactly the same way by JavaScript and PHP. It looks like your if statements are the ones wrongly/differently written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jQuery code is not how it should be, first of all, you are missing the id in your text field that you are checking in jquery:

```
<input type="text" name="testing" id="testing" />
```

And then you need `elseif` structure and `else` should go last:

```
if($("#testing").val()==1){
//do something
}
else if($("#testing").val()=="add"){
//do something
}
else if($("#testing").val()=="hello"){
//do something
}
else{
//do something
}
```

The `else` executes if none of the previous conditions resolved to true.

Comment: I think this is what OP actually wanted, even though code provided looks very different.  So +1 for mind-reading.

Answer (score 2):

the 3rd if is going to be proceeded, unless you make it:

else if($("#testing").val()=="hello"){

Comment: That would leave a syntax error, as you can't have an `else if` after `else`, so you'd have to change their order

Answer (score 0):

Explaination of if

```
//First If block is executed
if($("#testing").val()==1){
//do something
}
//This if will be executed separately from the previous
if($("#testing").val()=="add"){
//do something
}
else{
//do something
}
//This will also execute separately
if($("#testing").val()=="hello"){
//do something
}
```

In order to properly chain multiple exclusive if statements use "else if"

```
//First If block is executed
if($("#testing").val()==1){
//do something
}
//This if will be executed only if the first if is not
else if($("#testing").val()=="add"){
//do something
}
//else maintains standard usage as the final option
else{
//do something
}
//This will also execute separately
if($("#testing").val()=="hello"){
//do something
}
```